# Scraping data from a dynamic web page (.asp) with R

Tags: asp.net, r, xml, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrap some data using this code.

```
require(XML)
tables <-  readHTMLTable('http://fantasynba.movistarplus.es/basketball/reports/player_rankings.asp')
str(tables, max.level = 1)
df <- tables$searchResults
```

It works perfect but the problem is that it only gives me data for the first 188 observations that corresponds to the players whose position is "Base".  Whenever I try to get data from "Pivot" or "Alero" players, it gives me the same info. Since the url never changes, I don't know how to get this info.

Comment: As far as I know you can only do this by using `RSelenium` and simulate navigation